Fail building wheel for a package (petitRADTRANS)
I'm getting this error when trying to install the petitRADTRANS package.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (23.3.1)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Using cached pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-23.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.3.1
Successfully installed pip-24.0
PS C:\Users\bartl\Documents\.Uni\Project> pip install petitRADTRANS
Collecting petitRADTRANS
  Using cached petitRADTRANS-2.7.6.tar.gz (214 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from petitRADTRANS) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from petitRADTRANS) (1.11.4)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from petitRADTRANS) (3.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from petitRADTRANS) (3.9.0)
Collecting corner (from petitRADTRANS)
  Using cached corner-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: astropy in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from petitRADTRANS) (5.3.4)
Collecting exo_k (from petitRADTRANS)
  Using cached exo_k-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.3 kB)
Collecting molmass (from petitRADTRANS)
  Using cached molmass-2023.8.30-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from petitRADTRANS) (0.12.2)
Collecting pymultinest (from petitRADTRANS)
  Using cached pymultinest-2.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyerfa>=2.0 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from astropy->petitRADTRANS) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.13 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from astropy->petitRADTRANS) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=19.0 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from astropy->petitRADTRANS) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->petitRADTRANS) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->petitRADTRANS) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->petitRADTRANS) (4.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->petitRADTRANS) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->petitRADTRANS) (10.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->petitRADTRANS) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->petitRADTRANS) (2.8.2)
Collecting h5py (from petitRADTRANS)
  Using cached h5py-3.11.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite>=0.41.0 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from exo_k->petitRADTRANS) (0.42.0)
Collecting nestle<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 (from exo_k->petitRADTRANS)
  Using cached nestle-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numba>=0.58.0 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from exo_k->petitRADTRANS) (0.59.0)
Collecting numpy (from petitRADTRANS)
  Using cached numpy-1.25.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>2.0.3 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from exo_k->petitRADTRANS) (2.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from pandas>2.0.3->exo_k->petitRADTRANS) (2023.3.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from pandas>2.0.3->exo_k->petitRADTRANS) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in g:\other\conda\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib->petitRADTRANS) (1.16.0)
Using cached corner-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Using cached exo_k-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (174 kB)
Using cached h5py-3.11.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.0 MB)
Using cached numpy-1.25.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (15.5 MB)
Using cached molmass-2023.8.30-py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
Using cached pymultinest-2.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: petitRADTRANS
  Building wheel for petitRADTRANS (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [222 lines of output]
      C:\Users\bartl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcaw30o1\petitradtrans_8fe73fbd13604c148a52a56d8a949372\setup.py:5: DeprecationWarning:
     
        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
     
     
        from numpy.distutils.core import Extension, setup
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      INFO: build_src
      INFO: building extension "petitRADTRANS.fort_spec" sources
      INFO: f2py options: []
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\fortranobject.c' to sources.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS' to include_dirs.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\fort_spec-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\fort_spec-f2pywrappers2.f90' to sources.
      INFO: building extension "petitRADTRANS.fort_input" sources
      INFO: f2py options: []
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\fortranobject.c' to sources.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS' to include_dirs.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\fort_input-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\fort_input-f2pywrappers2.f90' to sources.
      INFO: building extension "petitRADTRANS.fort_rebin" sources
      INFO: f2py options: []
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\fortranobject.c' to sources.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS' to include_dirs.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\fort_rebin-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
      INFO: building extension "petitRADTRANS.retrieval.rebin_give_width" sources
      INFO: f2py options: []
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\retrieval\fortranobject.c' to sources.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\retrieval' to include_dirs.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\retrieval\rebin_give_width-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
      INFO: building extension "petitRADTRANS.poor_mans_nonequ_chem.chem_fortran_util.chem_fortran_util" sources
      INFO: f2py options: []
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\chem_fortran_util\fortranobject.c' to sources.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\chem_fortran_util' to include_dirs.
      INFO:   adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.11\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\chem_fortran_util\chem_fortran_util-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
      INFO: build_src: building npy-pkg config files
      G:\Other\Conda\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
      !!
     
              ********************************************************************************
              Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
              Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
              standards-based tools.
     
              See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
     
      !!
        self.initialize_options()
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      copying petitRADTRANS\nat_cst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      copying petitRADTRANS\physics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      copying petitRADTRANS\pyth_input.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      copying petitRADTRANS\radtrans.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      copying petitRADTRANS\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      copying petitRADTRANS\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      copying petitRADTRANS\_read_opacities.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      copying petitRADTRANS\__file_conversion.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      copying petitRADTRANS\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\context.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\reference_files_generators.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_chemistry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_fortran_modules.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_planet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_radtrans_correlated_k.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_radtrans_correlated_k_scattering.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_radtrans_correlated_k_surface_scattering.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_radtrans_line_by_line.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_radtrans_line_by_line_sampling.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_retrieval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\test_utility_functions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\_test_CO_line_lists.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\_test_data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\_test_H2O_line_lists.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\_test_high_res.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\_test_line_shapes_alkalis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\_test_TiO_line_lists.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      copying tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\ccf
      copying petitRADTRANS\ccf\ccf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\ccf
      copying petitRADTRANS\ccf\ccf_core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\ccf
      copying petitRADTRANS\ccf\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\ccf
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\cli
      copying petitRADTRANS\cli\eso_etc_cli.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\cli
      copying petitRADTRANS\cli\eso_skycalc_cli.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\cli
      copying petitRADTRANS\cli\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\cli
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\config
      copying petitRADTRANS\config\configuration.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\config
      copying petitRADTRANS\config\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\config
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\containers
      copying petitRADTRANS\containers\planet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\containers
      copying petitRADTRANS\containers\spectral_model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\containers
      copying petitRADTRANS\containers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\containers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem
      copying petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\chemistry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\cloud_cond.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\models.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\parameter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\plotting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\plot_style.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\preparing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\psis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\retrieval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\retrieval_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      copying petitRADTRANS\retrieval\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\retrieval
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\chem_fortran_util
      copying petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\chem_fortran_util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\chem_fortran_util
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\poor_mans_nonequ_chem
      copying petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\poor_mans_nonequ_chem.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\poor_mans_nonequ_chem
      copying petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\petitRADTRANS\poor_mans_nonequ_chem\poor_mans_nonequ_chem
      running build_ext
      INFO: No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      INFO: customize MSVCCompiler
      INFO: customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1086] : testing flags (/O2)
      creating C:\Users\bartl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphlhzflp7\Other
      creating C:\Users\bartl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphlhzflp7\Other\Conda
      creating C:\Users\bartl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphlhzflp7\Other\Conda\Lib
      creating C:\Users\bartl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphlhzflp7\Other\Conda\Lib\site-packages
      creating C:\Users\bartl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphlhzflp7\Other\Conda\Lib\site-packages\numpy
      creating C:\Users\bartl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphlhzflp7\Other\Conda\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils
      creating C:\Users\bartl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphlhzflp7\Other\Conda\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\checks
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1086] : testing flags (/WX)
      WARN: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1253] : feature 'AVX512_KNL' is disabled, MSVC compiler doesn't support it
      WARN: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1253] : feature 'AVX512_KNM' is disabled, MSVC compiler doesn't support it
      WARN: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1253] : feature 'AVX512_SPR' is disabled, MSVC compiler doesn't support it
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1795] : check requested baseline
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'SSE' with flags ()
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'SSE2' with flags ()
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'SSE3' with flags ()
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1804] : check requested dispatch-able features
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'POPCNT' with flags ()
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'SSE41' with flags ()
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1086] : testing flags (/arch:AVX)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'AVX' with flags (/arch:AVX)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1086] : testing flags (/arch:AVX2)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1086] : testing flags (/arch:AVX512)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'AVX512_SKX' with flags (/arch:AVX512)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'SSE42' with flags ()
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'AVX2' with flags (/arch:AVX2)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'FMA3' with flags (/arch:AVX2)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'SSSE3' with flags ()
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'F16C' with flags (/arch:AVX)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'AVX512CD' with flags (/arch:AVX512)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'AVX512F' with flags (/arch:AVX512)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'AVX512_CLX' with flags (/arch:AVX512)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'AVX512_CNL' with flags (/arch:AVX512)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1560] : testing feature 'AVX512_ICL' with flags (/arch:AVX512)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1816] : skip features (SSE SSE3 SSE2) since its part of baseline
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1820] : initialize targets groups
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1822] : parse target group simd_test
      INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_target_tokens[2033] : skip targets (VSX2 VSX4 VXE2 VSX VSX3 VXE XOP ASIMD NEON FMA4 VX) not part of baseline or dispatch-able features
      INFO: CCompilerOpt._parse_policy_not_keepbase[2145] : skip baseline features (SSE2)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.generate_dispatch_header[2366] : generate CPU dispatch header: (build\src.win-amd64-3.11\numpy\distutils\include\npy_cpu_dispatch_config.h)
      WARN: CCompilerOpt.generate_dispatch_header[2375] : dispatch header dir build\src.win-amd64-3.11\numpy\distutils\include does not exist, creating it
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_extra_checks[1640] : Testing extra checks for feature 'AVX512F' (AVX512F_REDUCE)
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.feature_extra_checks[1640] : Testing extra checks for feature 'AVX512_SKX' (AVX512BW_MASK AVX512DQ_MASK)
      INFO: get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      INFO: customize GnuFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable g77
      WARN: Could not locate executable f77
      INFO: customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable ifort
      WARN: Could not locate executable ifl
      INFO: customize AbsoftFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable f90
      INFO: customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      INFO: Found executable G:\Other\Conda\Library\usr\bin\DF.exe
      INFO: customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable efl
      INFO: customize Gnu95FCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable gfortran
      WARN: Could not locate executable f95
      INFO: customize G95FCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable g95
      INFO: customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      INFO: customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable efort
      WARN: Could not locate executable efc
      INFO: customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable flang
      WARN: don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      warning: build_ext: f77_compiler=None is not available.
     
      INFO: building 'petitRADTRANS.fort_spec' extension
      error: extension 'petitRADTRANS.fort_spec' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
      INFO:
      ########### EXT COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
      INFO: Platform      :
        Architecture: x64
        Compiler    : msvc
     
      CPU baseline  :
        Requested   : 'min'
        Enabled     : SSE SSE2 SSE3
        Flags       : none
        Extra checks: none
     
      CPU dispatch  :
        Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
        Enabled     : SSSE3 SSE41 POPCNT SSE42 AVX F16C FMA3 AVX2 AVX512F AVX512CD AVX512_SKX AVX512_CLX AVX512_CNL AVX512_ICL
        Generated   : none
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[864] : write cache to path -> C:\Users\bartl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcaw30o1\petitradtrans_8fe73fbd13604c148a52a56d8a949372\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for petitRADTRANS
  Running setup.py clean for petitRADTRANS
Failed to build petitRADTRANS
ERROR: Could not build wheels for petitRADTRANS, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I've tried to install fortran compiler via the intel website but it did not help. I've clean installed Anaconda, and updated my Python, updated pip, and honestly I don't know what to do. I am not familiar with these processes and programmes, but I need it to get installed.

"WARN: don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'" means that some part of the toolchain doesn't know how to compile Fortran code at all on Windows, so installing a Fortran compiler won't help unless you fix that to begin with. :( The documentation suggests using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), so if that's an option...
